# How to remove Jenkins build status from Github Pull Request

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to replace Jenkins by Github Actions as our CI/CD system. So far Github Actions is working great, but couldn't find where to disconnect/prevent Jenkins from reporting on Github, as seen on the image below.

[image]

As a result, our developers can't manage to merge the Pull Request by themselves. I've already disabled the project on Jenkins, unmarked the "GitHub Pull Request Builder" on the Build Triggers section of Jenkins, and looked everywhere on Github repository and organization to find any hooks/integrations with Github (found none).

Does anybody knows how to remove this "default Expected" from Jenkins? I cannot uninstall/remove jenkins-github plugin because a few other projects still use Jenkins as CI/CD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you show in your screenshot is not Jenkins reporting, but rather GitHub expecting to receive a Jenkins job, and not receiving it.

This is defined in the repository settings, under branches. Only people with admin rights on the repo can disable this.

Seems like you have a matching rule, probably on the master branch.

[image]

Comment: That was it!! Have admin rights to change this option, but it was a very hidden one. Thanks @DannyB

Comment: Ha agreed :D it has been 7 years, but I still could not find it!